# Authenticating HTTP requests to my web service

Tags: rest, http, authentication, web-applications, request

my situation is that I am writing a web service to expose data to an Android/iOs app that I plan to create.

I have never dealt with authentication for a REST API before so I was wondering if my idea of authentication is correct?

Would this be a correct process:

1. Client is authenticated with Facebook login and we generate a token for this client, stored in the db. This token will expire after some time. (what happens when it expires? do we generate another token during the next http request or just log the person out?)
2. Client makes http request, passing in the token in the query string
3. Check db if token is correct for this user
4. Give client access to the data or access to manipulation of the data

Thanks in advance for verifying my thoughts

Comment: Have you looked at [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)?

Answer (score 1):

In fact there are several levels of authentication that could use for your RESTful service. They are all based on the header `Accept`:

- **Basic authentication**. Username and password are hashed with base64 and set in this header.
- **Token-based authentication (OAuth2)**. This requires a token service that provides token(s) for users and manage expiration dates and token refreshing.

I think that this link could help you:

- **Implementing authentication with tokens for RESTful application** - https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/.

Hope it will help you,
Thierry